# Ambiguous occurrence error when try to define instance of a newType

Tags: haskell

I have the following code

```
newtype MyList a = MyList { getList :: [a] } deriving Show

instance Functor MyList where
fmap f x = MyList (fmap f (getList x))
```

And get the following error:

> It could refer to either ‘Prelude.fmap’ imported from ‘Prelude’ at
>   compile.hs:1:1 (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’) or ‘Main.fmap’,
>   defined at compile.hs:6:1

if I understand right. Is how if the new instance that I create for the new type affect the existing instance for the List [] type. But why it happens? I supposed that the objective of newtype was to create a different instance for the same type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your instance does not "supercede" or otherwise affect the regular list instance. This is merely a syntax confusion.

Haskell syntax is sensitive to indentation. In particular, class instance members should be indented further to the right relative to the word `instance`, like this:

```
instance Foo Bar where
    foo = ...
```

In your case, however, the definition of `fmap` is not indented this way. The compiler takes this to mean that you're declaring an "empty" instance `Functor MyList` (where "empty" means "without defining any methods" - which is technically a legal thing to do), and then, after the instance, and separately from it, you define a function named `fmap`.

Since a function with the same name is already defined in Prelude, the compiler doesn't know which one to pick when you're trying to call it - hence the error.

To fix this, simply indent your `fmap` definition to the right, like this:

```
instance Functor MyList where
    fmap f x = ...
```

Comment: (and as always, the ever unpopular option of writing out in full the explicit separators `{ ; }` would have prevented this error...)

Answer (score 4):

That's an indentation error. The code should instead be:

```
newtype MyList a = MyList { getList :: [a] } deriving Show

instance Functor MyList where
    fmap f x = MyList (fmap f (getList x))
```